# How to programmatically find buffer visiting specific directory

Tags: buffers, dired

I'm looking for something similar to `(find-buffer-visiting FILENAME &optional PREDICATE)` that would find a dired-mode buffer visiting a specified directory.  Something like:

`(find-buffer-visiting-dir DIRNAME)`

The built-in `find-buffer-visiting` only searches buffer visiting files quite unfortunately. It checks if the buffer has a local buffer-file-name variable bound. The optional PREDICATE is therefore used only on files.

A potential improvement for that function would be to write
`(find-buffer-visiting FILENAME &optional PREDICATE FILTER)` where FILTER would be a filter function used on all buffers to determine if the buffer should be included in the search.

Is there something like this already available?

Comment: If you are using `dired+` you can check `diredp--reuse-dir-buffer-helper`. Several interactive commands in `dired+` use this helper. But, I am not sure whether it really does what you want. (Your question smells a bit like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: I wrote a command that opens a file at point and which simply moves point to a window already opening that file.  I wanted it to work for directories as well and in my code I'm using find-buffer-visiting on the filename to get the buffer.  So I was looking to expand on that call either by replacing it with a function being able to detect the buffer of a directory or adding a or form which would then call the second function identifying the buffer of a directory.  I don't think it was an XY-problem.  The solution is to use the dired-buffers-for-dir as Drew pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for function `dired-buffers-for-dir`.

[Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) enhances this function, but even the vanilla Emacs version is OK. `C-h f dired-buffers-for-dir` tells you (this is the Dired+ doc string):

> **`dired-buffers-for-dir`** is a compiled Lisp function in [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> `(dired-buffers-for-dir DIR &optional FILE SUBDIRS-P)`
>
> Return a list of buffers that Dired `DIR` (top level or in-situ subdir).
>
> `DIR` is automatically expanded with `expand-file-name` using the
> `default-directory`.  If you need expansion relative to some other
> directory then do that before calling `dired-buffers-for-dir`.
>
> If `FILE` is non-`nil`, include only those whose wildcard pattern (if any)
> matches `FILE`.
>
> If `SUBDIRS-P` is non-`nil`, also include the Dired buffers of directories
> below `DIR`.
>
> The list is in reverse order of buffer creation, most recent last.
> As a side effect, killed Dired buffers for DIR are removed from
> `dired-buffers`.

In general, if it seems like there should be a utility function for dealing with files or directories, or their names etc., then it's likely that there is in fact such a function. Remember that the `apropos` commands are your friends. In this case, just `M-x apropos dired buffer` shows you this function (and others).

Comment: I'll definitively have to use `apropos` more often.

Comment: There are additional apropos commands and non-interactive functions, in particular `apropos-documentation`.

Comment: I know,  they're all very useful.  `apropos-value` is quite useful too. I have just not developed the habit to use them enough.